# Difference between double dispatch and visitor pattern in Java and C++

Tags: java, c++, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

Is there any difference between double dispatch and visitor pattern?

I'm working with Java and C++ and wondering if there is any split between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visitor pattern is a means of adding a new operation to existing classes. Double dispatch is a means of dispatching function calls with respect to two (or, when generalised, more) polymorphic types, rather than a single polymorphic type, which is what languages like C++ and Java support directly.

Comment: I'll have to study this more carefully - it appears that I'm mistaken.  Thanks for the instruction, Neil.